# Issues deploying large contracts with Web3.JS , but with Remix contract deploys perfectly

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, contract-deployment, ganache

I am using `solc` npm package as compiler. It seems to compile fine. **Maybe it's not a gas issue, but a problem with how I'm deploying multipart contracts in Web3 JS.**

```
//initial.js
var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));   
console.log("Result : ", output); // displays fine
    
ABI = output.contracts["initial.sol"]["goblintownNFT"].abi;
bytecode = output.contracts["initial.sol"]["goblintownNFT"].evm.bytecode.object;
console.log("Bytecode: ", bytecode); // displays fine
console.log("ABI: ", ABI); // displays fine

contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, {data: bytecode });
web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => {

    mainAccount = accounts[0];

    contract
        .deploy({ data: bytecode })
        .send({ from: mainAccount, gas: 10000000 })
        .on("receipt", (receipt) => {
  
            // Contract Address will be returned here
            console.log("Contract Address:", receipt.contractAddress);
        })
});
```

I have no issue deploying small contracts, but I get the following error when trying to deploy large contracts (such as Goblintown contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0xbce3781ae7ca1a5e050bd9c4c77369867ebc307e#code ) `RuntimeError: abort(Error: Returned error: Exceeds block gas limit). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.` However these large contracts deploy without issue on Remix.

What changes can be done, to successfully deploy large contracts on Web3.JS?

Web3JS docs https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.2/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy

Comment: You can take a look at this resource to see changes you can make to successfully deploy large contracts by mitigating the exceed block gas limit: https://vmexceptionwhileprocessingtransactionrevert.com/

Comment: The link you sent me said `If you're using solc directly, use the --optimize --runs=1 parameters via the docs.` but I didn't understand how to modify my code to do this. Do you know how I can modify my code?